# How to Copy-PasteSpecial cells from filtered range

Tags: excel, vba

Here's my code below.

```
Sub AddExistingItemToRWP()
Dim AddRow As Integer
Dim eLastRow As Integer
AddRow = Worksheets("Recipe Workarea-Product").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
eLastRow = Worksheets("Additional Existing Raw Mat.").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim Rng As Range
Sheets("Additional Existing Raw Mat.").Select
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
With Sheet12
    With .Range("$A$1:K" & eLastRow)
         .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=("Y")
         .SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)
         .Offset(1, 0) _
         .Copy Destination:=Sheet8.Range("H" & AddRow + 1)
         .PasteSpecial Paste = xlPasteValues

    End With
End With
AutoFillCols (AddRow)
Sheets("Additional Existing Raw Mat.").Select
End Sub
```

The .pastespecial cells seems to be not working. What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: it works but it returns an error because the "paste" is empty. how do i ignore this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four things:

1. `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` returns a reference to a range, but you don't use it
2. You can't use *both* `Destination:= ...` and `.PasteSpecial` with one `Copy`.  Choose one.
3. You mean `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`  not `.PasteSpecial Paste = xlPasteValues`
4. You activate and filter sheet `"Additional Existing Raw Mat."`, then refer to a filter on `Sheet12`.  Are you sure thats right?

**Update:** 
How to use Copy PasteSpecial

```
.Copy 
Sheet8.Range("H" & AddRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thank ou for your answer. So how do I copy a range of filtered cells from a worksheet and paste it using the .PasteSpecial to another sheet? Sorry I don't know much in vba programming.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got the solution to my problem. Here's my code:

```
Sub AddExistingItemToRWP()
Dim AddRow As Integer
Dim eLastRow As Integer
AddRow = Worksheets("Recipe Workarea-Product").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
eLastRow = Worksheets("Additional Existing Raw Mat.").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim Rng As Range

Sheets("Additional Existing Raw Mat.").Select
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
With Sheet12
    With .Range("$A$1:K" & eLastRow)
         .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=("Y")
         .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
         Selection.Offset(1, 0).Copy
         Sheets("Recipe Workarea-Product").Select
         Range("H" & AddRow + 1).Select
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    End With
End With

AutoFillCols (AddRow)
Sheets("Additional Existing Raw Mat.").Select

End Sub
```